# Download excel file issue

Tags: php, codeigniter, download

****I am new to codeigniter now i am stuck in downloading a file from server. Basically I am facing two problem one downloading is happening whenver i go to page.and also that excel file im downloading is not readable after download :(*** 
.So any suggestion will b great Thanks in advance :)
Happy Coding.*

```
    <input type="<?php 
$this->load->helper('download');
$name = 'ruby_new.xlsx';
$data = file_get_contents("./downloads/ruby_new.xlsx"); // Read the file's contents - cannot use relative path. It will try to call the file from same directory (controller) as this file. In order for it get the contents from the root folder put a . in front of the relative path//
force_download($name, $data); 
 ?>" class="btn btn-primary btn-small" value="download demo">
```

Comment: Hey Mr Srinavas i cant understand what are u saying :(

Comment: no its in 2007 format.i dont know why its saying file is courrupted

Comment: Try to add download code in any controller method and redirect the page onclick

Comment: where you have integrated this code? i mean in controller or in view?

Comment: Ya did now im downloading through a button but still its showing excel file is corrupted.

Comment: i am calling through a class named dashboard and their i have a function named download.this code is integrated in view

Comment: haaa got an idea...now im putting tht excel file into rar and downloading the rar file so that excel file is not getting corrupted